# How to trigger Android theme change via adb shell for one app only?

Tags: android, adb, android-source, android-theme

I know I can change theme in adb shell with

```
adb shell cmd uimode night yes
adb shell cmd uimode night no
```

But this triggers a theme change for the entire system. Is there a way to isolate this theme change for only a single app?